# How to show a hypothesis test is invariant under some transfomation?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, invariance

How Can I show a test statistics invariant under specific transformation like shift or scalar or orthogonal transformation. Is there any routine way to do that? Is it enough to show that test statistics not changes with general form of the transformation?

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Show that the test statistic does not change, for example the Z-Test for one sample is invariant to multiplication:

$ \frac{\bar{x} - \mu}{\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}} $ If we will multiply it we will get:

$Var(a x) = a^2 \sigma $

$ \frac{a \bar{x} - a\mu}{\frac{a\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}} =  \frac{\bar{x} - \mu}{\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}}$

That is, transform your data and show that the test statistic does not change as a result.

Comment: and what about orthogonal transformations?

Comment: It's not enough just to write down how the statistic transforms: you also need to demonstrate that the hypotheses and the critical region of the test transform in compatible ways so that when the transformation is applied to the entire problem description it does not change the *decisions* (reject or not reject) that would be made in any circumstance.